# How to use Tika via PHP when both installed on one server?

Tags: php, apache-tika

- I need to make an internal website which allows users to upload .doc, .pdf, .xls files and see the text in a textarea box.
- I have created the site in PHP to the point where a user can upload the files.
- I have installed Tika on my server and at the command line can type `java -jar tika-app-1.10-SNAPSHOT.jar -m manu.pdf > output.txt` which successfully creates the text I need in the output file.

**What is the best way to call Tika from PHP in order to get the plain text of an uploaded file into PHP?**

Searching around I find:

1. PHP code that makes calls to a "Tika server" e.g. with cURL
2. PHP Wrapper classes for Tika which seem to use Tika on the same server that PHP is installed on, but I have not gotten any of them to work.
3. Alternatively, I could simply call Tika via the `exec` command.

But I'm not sure what is the easiest way to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is on your own managed servers, and both *PHP* and *Tika* locations are known to you, just use `exec`.
Or if you prefer better control (which I suspect you do not need) use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec)
If you have some performance issues, and/or need to scale this thing, then there is room for a more elaborate solution.

Answer (score 4):

## Simpler approach (call API)

For running on a remote server I suggest you to use `curl` or `Guzzle` to call the address (but you could also simply use `file_get_contents` and pass it the URL for the API that will call *Tika* on the remote server.

## Other approach (execute process on local server)

For running the parsing on local (*Tika* and *PHP* on same server) I used [Synfony/Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

I'd, personally, discourage you from just using `exec`.

---

I would add that having Tika on another server will force you to send this server the whole file payload uploaded from the user.
While a faster solution would be to just receive the upload, with PHP execution, and directly call the Tika process from the same script (or at least from the same machine).
Otherwise you need a script that:

- receives the uploaded data
- **uploads** that to the *Tika* server (maybe as payload of an API call)
- tells to *Tika* (through API) on the remote server to parse the file
- **downloads** the response parsed data
- works with it or display it.

As I highlighed there will be a lot more overhead just as communication between the two servers; and that is not desirable when the file to parse is maybe a 35MB pdf-file, is it?
The user would have to wait, let's say, 2 minutes for the upload, **PLUS** other, let's say, 20 seconds to send the file to the *Tika* server, and then other, let's say 3 seconds to get the text-format parsed result.

I strongly suggest to stay and work on the same *PHP* server.